# Location counter (.) update in linker script

Tags: gcc, counter, ld, linker-scripts

I have a problem with the location counter in a linker script. Don't know if this is a bug or if I'm expecting the wrong output.

I have a bss section

```
/* Program bss, zeroed out during init. */
.bss :
{
    . = ALIGN(4);
    __bss_start = .;
    *(.bss*)
    *(.COMMON*)
    . = ALIGN(4);
    __bss_end = .;
    __heap_start = .;
} >sram_u
__bss_size = SIZEOF(.bss);
```

My problem is that `(__bss_end - __bss_start)` is not equal to `__bss_size`. If I instead assign `__bss_end` outside the `.bss` section I get the expected value. If I check the sections headers with elfread I get the expected `.bss` size.

The linker I'm using is:

```
GNU ld (GNU Tools for ARM Embedded Processors) 2.23.2.20131129
Copyright 2012 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This program is free software; you may redistribute it under the terms of
the GNU General Public License version 3 or (at your option) a later version.
This program has absolutely no warranty.
```

And GCC

```
arm-none-eabi-gcc (GNU Tools for ARM Embedded Processors) 4.8.3 20131129 (release)
[ARM/embedded-4_8-branch revision 205641]
Copyright (C) 2013 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE
```

So the question is if the location counter (`.`) should be updated inside a section definition or am I just using it wrong?

PS: Hope I'm using the correct terms...

Answer (score 3):

The problem was that there was a . before COMMON. The linker script should say

```
.bss :
{
    . = ALIGN(4);
    __bss_start = .;
    *(.bss*)
    *(COMMON*)
    . = ALIGN(4);
    __bss_end = .;
    __heap_start = .;
} >sram_u
__bss_size = SIZEOF(.bss);
```

Something I missed even when looking in the map file. The linker would put COMMON in bss as default but this would not be seen by __bss_end inside the .bss section. Moving __bss_end outside the bss section declaration would capture it. Removed the COMMON block by adding -fno-common to gcc.